# Unexpected token in JSON at position 250

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion

I am new to javascript. I have a form that looks up doctors based on city and zip code. However, for the city drop down, there is one particular city that renders an error. I am not sure why for that particular city, it throws the JSON Error. The only thing I can think of is when the value is being passed, there might be a hidden value.

[image: SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON]

The following is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
         <SELECT name="proCity" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
                   <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> 
                      <option value=""></option>
                      <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                       <option value=#trim(city)#>#trim(city)#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select>

        <!---<select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option><option ng-repeat="c in Cities">{{c.City}}</option> </select>--->
        </div>

    $scope.GetCityList = function (){
        try{
            $http.get("/includes/remote/ReturnCityList.cfm")
                .then(function(response){
                    $scope.Cities = response.data.Cities;
                })
        }
        catch(err){}
    }
```

The following is in coldfusion where it retrieves the table that contains the cities:

```
<cfoutput>
<cftry>
    <cfquery name="Cities" datasource="W">
        declare @tmpTable table ( col1 nvarchar(255) )

        insert into @tmpTable
        select distinct city 
        from providerWeb_Multiple 
        where isnull(city,'') <> ''
        order by city

        declare @tmp nvarchar(max) = ''

        select @tmp = RTRIM(LTRIM(@tmp)) 
                +  ',{"value":"' + col1 + '"}'
        from @tmpTable

        select '{"Cities":[' + stuff(@tmp,1,1,'') + ']}' as col
    </cfquery>
    <cfoutput>
        #Cities.col#
    </cfoutput>
    <cfcatch type="Any">
        <!---<cfoutput>#cfcatch.Message#<br />
        #cfcatch.Detail#</cfoutput>--->
        <cfoutput>An error has been detected. Please contact us with this problem. Thanks!</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Okay, after a little more testing, there isn't any special characters being passed. I believe it has to do with the following js file that I created that might be the issue but again, I don't see it:

```
    (
function(){
    var $scope, $location;
    var indexApp = angular.module('indexApp',['ui.bootstrap']);

    indexApp.controller('IndexController',function($scope,$http,$location,anchorSmoothScroll){
        $scope.Lang = 'initVal';
        $scope.ShowResults = false;
        $scope.ShowDesc = true;
        $scope.NoResults = false;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.maxPageNumbersToShow = 10;
        $scope.formModel = {};
        $scope.searchMode = 0;
        $scope.miles =  [{'value':'5'},{'value':'10'},{'value':'15'},{'value':'20' }];
        $scope.Specialties = [{'value':'Family practice'},{'value':'General practice'},{'value':'Internal medicine'},{'value':'Pediatrics'}];
        $scope.Gender = [{'value':'Male'},{'value':'Female'}];
        $scope.Languages = {};
        $scope.Cities = {};
        $scope.searchParam = {};
        $("input").removeAttr('disabled');

        $scope.searchParam.Distance = $scope.miles[0];

        $scope.GetCurrentZip = function (){
            try{
                var lon, lat;
                // console.log('starting geoposition code.');
                if("geolocation" in navigator){
                    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
                        lat = pos.coords.latitude.toFixed(3);
                        lon = pos.coords.longitude.toFixed(3);
                        // console.log(lat + ' ' + lon);
                        $http.get("/includes/remote/ReturnCurrentZipcode.cfm?Lat=" + lat + "&Lon=" + lon)
                        .then(function(response){
                            $scope.searchParam.Zip = response.data;
                        })
                    })
                }
                else{ console.log('No geolocation'); }
            }
            catch(err) { console.log(err.message); }
        }

        $scope.GetCityList = function (){
            try{
                $http.get("/includes/remote/ReturnCityList.cfm")
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.Cities = response.data.Cities;
                    })
            }
            catch(err){}
        }

        $scope.GetLangList = function (){
            try{
                $http.get("/includes/remote/ReturnLangList.cfm")
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.Languages = response.data.Languages;
                    })
            }
            catch(err){}
        }

        $scope.SearchProvider = function(searchParam){
            try{
                $scope.searchMode = 1;
                var queryString='';
                if($scope.formModel && $scope.formModel !== searchParam){
                    $scope.resultsCount = 0;
                    currentPage = 1;
                }
                if(searchParam){
                    $scope.formModel = searchParam;
                    for(var param in searchParam){
                        if(searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param)){
                            var paramValue = searchParam[param].value ? searchParam[param].value.trim() : searchParam[param].trim();
                            if (paramValue.length > 0)
                                queryString += param + '=' + paramValue + '&';
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(queryString);
                queryString= '?' + queryString + 'currentpage=' + $scope.currentPage;

                $http.get("/includes/remote/ReturnProvidersList.cfm" + queryString)
                .then(function(response){
                    $scope.providers = response.data.provider;
                    $scope.resultsCount = response.data.rowCount;
                    if (!$scope.providers){
                            $scope.NoResults = true;
                            $scope.ShowResults = false;
                            $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        }
                    else{
                            $scope.NoResults = false;
                            $scope.ShowResults = true;
                            $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        }
                })
            }
            catch(err){ alert('No response.: ' + err.message); }
        }

        $scope.$watchGroup(['currentPage'], function(){
            try{
                if($scope.searchMode == 1){
                    $scope.SearchProvider($scope.formModel);
                    }
            }
            catch(err){}
        });


        $scope.GetCityList();
        $scope.GetLangList();
        $scope.GetCurrentZip();

        $scope.gotoElement = function (eID){
            //http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/y65G5/
              // set the location.hash to the id of
              // the element you wish to scroll to.

            //$location.hash('bottom');

              // call $anchorScroll()
            var browserWidth = screen.availWidth;
            if (browserWidth < 768)
                anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo(eID);
        };

    });

    indexApp.service('anchorSmoothScroll', function(){
        this.scrollTo = function(eID) {

            // This scrolling function 
            // is from http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript

            var startY = currentYPosition();
            var stopY = elmYPosition(eID);
            var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
            if (distance < 100) {
                scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
            }
            var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
            if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
            var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
            var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
            var timer = 0;
            if (stopY > startY) {
                for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
                    setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                    leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
                } return;
            }
            for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
                setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
            }

            function currentYPosition() {
                // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
                // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                    return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
                if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
                return 0;
            }

            function elmYPosition(eID) {
                var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
                var y = elm.offsetTop;
                var node = elm;
                while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
                    node = node.offsetParent;
                    y += node.offsetTop;
                } return y;
            }

        };

    });

    indexApp.directive('allowPattern',[allowPatternDirective]);
    indexApp.directive('popPopup',[describePopup]);
    indexApp.directive('pop', function pop ($tooltip, $timeout) {
    var tooltip = $tooltip('pop', 'pop', 'event');
    var compile = angular.copy(tooltip.compile);
    tooltip.compile = function (element, attrs) {      
      var first = true;
      attrs.$observe('popShow', function (val) {
        if (JSON.parse(!first || val || false)) {
            $timeout(function(){
                element.triggerHandler('event');
            });
            }
            first = false;
        });
        return compile(element, attrs);
        };
        return tooltip;
    });

    indexApp.filter('PhoneNumber', function(){
    return function(phoneNumber){
        var dash = '-';
        var openParen = '(';
        var closeParen = ') ';
        if(phoneNumber){
            var pn = phoneNumber;
            pn = [pn.slice(0, 6), dash, pn.slice(6)].join('');
            pn = openParen + [pn.slice(0, 3), closeParen, pn.slice(3)].join('');
            return pn;
            }
        return phoneNumber;
        }
    });

    indexApp.filter('Zip', function(){
    return function(zipcode){
        var dash = '-';
        if(zipcode && zipcode.length > 5){
            var zc = zipcode;
            zc = [zc.slice(0, 5), dash, zc.slice(5)].join('');
            return zc;
            }
        return zipcode;
        }
    });

    function allowPatternDirective(){
        return{
            restrict: "A",
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){
                return function(scope, element, attrs){
                    element.bind("keypress", function(event){
                        var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
                        var keyCodeChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);

                        if(!keyCodeChar.match(new RegExp(attrs.allowPattern, "i"))){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function describePopup(){
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: { title: '@', content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&' },
            templateUrl: 'template/popover/popover.html'
            };
        }
})();
(function($) {
  // @todo Document this.
  $.extend($,{ placeholder: {
      browser_supported: function() {
        return this._supported !== undefined ?
          this._supported :
          ( this._supported = !!('placeholder' in $('<input type="text">')[0]) );
      },
      shim: function(opts) {
        var config = {
          color: '#888',
          cls: 'placeholder',
          selector: 'input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]'
        };
        $.extend(config,opts);
        return !this.browser_supported() && $(config.selector)._placeholder_shim(config);
      }
  }});

  $.extend($.fn,{
    _placeholder_shim: function(config) {
      function calcPositionCss(target)
      {
        var op = $(target).offsetParent().offset();
        var ot = $(target).offset();

        return {
          top: ot.top - op.top,
          left: ot.left - op.left,
          width: $(target).width()
        };
      }
      function adjustToResizing(label) {
        var $target = label.data('target');
        if(typeof $target !== "undefined") {
          label.css(calcPositionCss($target));
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(label); });
        }
      }
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.is(':visible') ) {

          if( $this.data('placeholder') ) {
            var $ol = $this.data('placeholder');
            $ol.css(calcPositionCss($this));
            return true;
          }

          var possible_line_height = {};
          if( !$this.is('textarea') && $this.css('height') != 'auto') {
            possible_line_height = { lineHeight: $this.css('height'), whiteSpace: 'nowrap' };
          }

          var isBorderBox = ($this.css('box-sizing') === 'border-box');
          var isTextarea = $this.is('textarea');

          var ol = $('<label />')
            .text($this.attr('placeholder'))
            .addClass(config.cls)
            .css($.extend({
              position:'absolute',
              display: 'inline',
              'float':'none',
              overflow:'hidden',
              textAlign: 'left',
              color: config.color,
              cursor: 'text',
              paddingTop: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-top'),
              paddingRight: $this.css('padding-right'),
              paddingBottom: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-bottom'),
              paddingLeft: $this.css('padding-left'),
              fontSize: $this.css('font-size'),
              fontFamily: $this.css('font-family'),
              fontStyle: $this.css('font-style'),
              fontWeight: $this.css('font-weight'),
              textTransform: $this.css('text-transform'),
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              zIndex: 99,
            }, possible_line_height))
            .css(calcPositionCss(this))
            .attr('for', this.id)
            .data('target',$this)
            .click(function(){
                if (!$(this).data('target').is(':disabled')) {
                    $(this).data('target').focus();
                }
            })
            .insertBefore(this);
            $this
                .data('placeholder', ol)
                .on('keydown', function () {
                    ol.hide();
                })
                .on('blur change', function () {
                    ol[$this.val().length ? 'hide' : 'show']();
                })
                .triggerHandler('blur');
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(ol); });
        }
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).add(window).bind('ready load', function() {
  if (jQuery.placeholder) {
    jQuery.placeholder.shim();
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**
As suggested by @Leigh, I tried my best to focus on the main issue and select the code that is being to generate the result.

The following code is what is used to display the cities:

```
<div class="form-group">
         <SELECT name="proCity" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
                   <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> 
                      <option value=""></option>
                      <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                       <option value=#trim(city)#>#trim(city)#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select>

        <!---<select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option><option ng-repeat="c in Cities">{{c.City}}</option> </select>--->
        </div>
```

The following is the js file that I am using to pass the value to the database and then retrieve the result:

```
    function(){
    var $scope, $location;
    var indexApp = angular.module('indexApp',['ui.bootstrap']);

    indexApp.controller('IndexController',function($scope,$http,$location,anchorSmoothScroll){
        $scope.Lang = 'initVal';
        $scope.ShowResults = false;
        $scope.ShowDesc = true;
        $scope.NoResults = false;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.maxPageNumbersToShow = 10;
        $scope.formModel = {};
        $scope.searchMode = 0;
        $scope.miles =  [{'value':'5'},{'value':'10'},{'value':'15'},{'value':'20' }];
        $scope.Specialties = [{'value':'Family practice'},{'value':'General practice'},{'value':'Internal medicine'},{'value':'Pediatrics'}];
        $scope.Gender = [{'value':'Male'},{'value':'Female'}];
        $scope.Languages = {};
        $scope.Cities = {};
        $scope.searchParam = {};
        $("input").removeAttr('disabled');
$scope.GetCityList = function (){
            try{
                $http.get("/includes/remote/ReturnCityList.cfm")
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.Cities = response.data.Cities;
                    })
            }
            catch(err){}
        }
```

The following is the ReturnCityList.cfm file:

```
    <cftry>
    <cfquery name="Cities" datasource="Wa">
        declare @tmpTable table ( col1 nvarchar(255) )

        insert into @tmpTable
        select distinct city 
        from providerWeb_Multiple 
        where isnull(city,'') <> ''
        order by city

        declare @tmp nvarchar(max) = ''

        select @tmp = RTRIM(LTRIM(@tmp)) 
                +  ',{"value":"' + col1 + '"}'
        from @tmpTable

        select '{"Cities":[' + stuff(@tmp,1,1,'') + ']}' as col
    </cfquery>
    <cfoutput>
        #Cities.col#
    </cfoutput>
    <cfcatch type="Any">
        <!---<cfoutput>#cfcatch.Message#<br />
        #cfcatch.Detail#</cfoutput>--->
        <cfoutput>An error has been detected. Please contact us with this problem. Thanks!</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: Without seeing the actual string generated, my guess is some of the values contain special character that need to be escaped. Do not roll your own JSON. Instead use [serializeJSON](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html) (which has a few quirks) or one of the existing JSON libraries out there.

Comment: @Leigh I am not using my own JSON. I am using angular.min.js ver. 1.4.4

Comment: Why not use the unminified version of angular and add a breakpoint so you can inspect whatever you are converting to JSON.

Comment: @JAEGERNINJA you are using your own json, you're creating it with your query... `select '{"Cities":[' + stuff(@tmp,1,1,'') + ']}' as col` you should instead create a coldfusion array or struct with the data and then serialize it to json.

Comment: @KevinB yes you are correct, still learning

Comment: @KevinB I updated my question. I do not believe it is causing the issue. I think its my poorly written js file that I created

Comment: @JAEGERNINJA has the error changed? if it hasn't, then no your angular code is unrelated. If it has, then you should ask a new question because it has fundamentally changed and you have invalidated existing answers, which is really bad form.

Comment: @KevinB The error has not change and I think you are right. I will post a new question that reflects with what I believe might be the issue that is causing the error to show

Comment: @Beginner Thats how I know determine it was the json

Comment: @KevinB No, sorry I misread your question. No, the error has not change. Same error and I believe is the js file that I created that I think its causing the issue. It is through there that the value is passed to retrieve the city info. But as I go through it, I don't see the issue

Comment: (Edit) The timing clashes of the edits is making the responses very confusing ;-) So have you guys determined the problem is the manually created JSON string or some other javascript? If it is the JSON, can you post a sanitized example of the *generated* JSON string?

Comment: I don't know what's goin on anymore

Comment: @Leigh what do you mean by sanitized?

Comment: @KevinB so the edit I did, I believe it is the js file I posted. It is their where its passing the values. Again, when I look at it, it looks fine

Comment: ie Standard procedure when posting data to a public site, ie Remove any proprietary or sensitive values from the sample data before posting. Though if it is just a list of cities, it is probably okay as is.

Comment: @Leigh ahhh okay thank you for clarifying. No, it just a list of cities, no sensitive data. Um... yeah. again, I am currently reviewing the js file I posted and I just dont see logic error or syntax error

Comment: (Edit) That is more code than I have time to review right now :), but .. I did notice the code is swallowing errors, ie `catch(err){}`. At the very least, write errors to the console otherwise so you know there is a problem. BTW, best to post a [self contained](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example (when possible). Typically the easier it is for others to run the code, the faster you will get an answer :)

Comment: @Leigh okay thank you for the advise. Sorry still very new. I will see what I can do. Thank You

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your json string contains some invalid Unicode char

> When this test finished, I found the following ASCII control
>   characters to be problematic when delivered as inline JSON:
>
> 8232 - Line Separator
>
> 8233 - Paragraph Separator

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2576-testing-which-ascii-characters-break-json-javascript-object-notation-parsing.htm